# Changing boolean value in class function in java

Tags: java

Can we modify a Boolean value in class function in java, something like this wont work as the change is local to function. How can we make the following change passed variable reflect outside the method call?

```
public void changeboolean(Boolean b)
{
        if( somecondition )
        {
                b=true;
        }
        else
        {
                b=false;
        }
}
```

EDIT
 The code could be like this:

```
public String changeboolean(Boolean b,int show)
{
        if( somecondition )
        {
                b=true;
                show=1;
                return "verify again";
        }
        else
        {
                b=false;
                show=2;
                return "Logout";
        }
        show=3;
        return verifed;

}
```

I'm searching for something like this

```
b.setvalue(true);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you return a boolean instead?

Comment: Why don't you just make the method return the new boolean value?

Comment: Someone needs to read a Java book.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it misses C# `ref` and `out` keywords...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Can we modify a Boolean value in class function in java

No, `Boolean` is immutable, like all the wrappers for the primitive types.

Options:

- Return a `boolean` from your method (best choice)
- Create a mutable equivalent of `Boolean` which allows you to set the embedded value. You would then need to modify the value *within the instance* that the parameter refers to - changing the value of the parameter to refer to a different instance wouldn't help you, because arguments are always passed by value in Java. That value is either a primitive value or a reference, but it's still *passed by value*. Changing the value of a parameter never changes the caller's variable.
- Use a `boolean[]` with a single element as the wrapper type
- Use `AtomicBoolean` as the wrapper type

Comment: For all the lazy people who want to do #2, there's *cough* [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) available in the JDK (hey I didn't say that that was a good idea ;) ).

Comment: Another common trick is to accept a `boolean[]` of length 1, and to set `array[0] = result`.

Comment: The array trick mentioned by Louis is probably the best way to accomplish this.  The situation comes up when you need to change *multiple* boolean values, so "just return the new value" isn't enough (Java, sadly, can't cope with the idea of returning more than one value from a function).  Arrays are always mutable, and while this design doesn't scale well, it's perfectly fine for routines used in one area, hidden from view.

Comment: @TiStrga: Have added that and AtomicBoolean as options.

Comment: why `AtomicBoolean` is suggested last? I think you could just write only one answer with that class, `AtomicBoolean` is solution

Comment: try AtomicBoolean

Comment: @alim: That's already listed in the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Boolean is immutable, like all the wrappers for the primitive types.
Soln:
Trying using MutableBoolean of apacheCommon
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableBoolean.html

Comment: But it is added in later versions only.